# Can I find out all of the objects in a generation of the garbage collector?

Tags: .net, garbage-collection, clr, memory-profiling

I was struck by the thought that it might be interesting if an app could scan what objects are hanging around in its generation 2 or large object heap in the garbage collector periodically, and see if it could spot things that linger around for a really long time/forever. The general idea behind it being that an app could determine potential objects that are resource leaks if the same thing was present for multiple collections (tracking them by weak references, so that the act of profiling it doesn't keep it around). I can find ways to ask what generation a specific object is in, and I can find APIs for unmanaged code or debugging tools to investigate the managed heaps, but what I really want is a managed call to give me some sort of data structure with all the objects in a specified generation.

Do I have any hope of finding such a thing, or am I looking for something that doesn't exist?

Theoretically it may be possible to shell out an instance of a debugger app and parse the results or something, but I'd like it to run on live web servers during times of low load, and I'm not sure that ops would like me attaching a debugger, even if it was possible :)

Answer (score 2):

Having recently worked with similar tools in Objective-C land, you might want to look for a heap-shot tool. A heapshot tool will take snapshots of your heap, build a memory graph from it and tries to find out which memory is rooted and where. Much of this is similar to the way a garbage collector finds out which objects to collect.

In general, a heapshot tool allows you to take snapshots of your heap at different times and compare what memory is rooted and which objects do take up that space. Mono Heapshot https://github.com/mono/heap-shot seems to be a good starting point here, although I havent personaly used it. I have had good results with JetBrains dotTrace Memory in the past. Unfortunately, both of these tools wont show you the generations an object lives in, but they can track object identity, sometimes even across snapshots. If you find an object survives multiple collections, it will likely live in a higher generation. The exact generation is implementation, runtime and environment specific though.

Other memory profilers certainly exist. A very good tool on the Microsoft CLR is WinDbg plus SOS extensions. Theres a good msdn magazine article about it here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163528.aspx  and I found Tess from the (wonderfully named) "If broken it is, fix it you should" blog has great content too. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/

Some general information about the structure of your heap and the GC generations can be retrieved via a set of performance counters documented at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x2tyfybc.aspx.

Comment: Thanks for the thoughts. I shall try to get some time to trawl through heap-shot. It wants to be used separately from the app it's looking at, rather than being a part of it (see command line:mono --profile=heap-shot MyProgram.exe) but there may be some tricks I can use. the windbg stuff and whatnot is all what i've seen so far, and definitely is outside of the running app :(